# Regex pattern for matching url

Tags: regex, regex-negation

i have the following pattern : `/^\/(?P<slug>.+)$/` that match : `/url`.

My problem is that it also match `/url/page`, how to ignore `/`in this regex ?

The pattern should:

- Pattern match : `/url`
- Pattern don't match : `/url/page`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^\/(?P<slug>[^\/]+)$/
```

`[^\/]` matches every character that is not a slash (`^` at the beginning of a character class negates the class). I recommend to have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to learn more about regular expressions.